# Where are hive tables stored in Azure storage account?

Tags: database, azure, apache-spark, hive

If I create a table using Hive, where is the table itself stored in the Azure storage account?

My intention is that I want to copy the tables and metastore to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From micro soft docs,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-hive-tables) If you do not specify   ,(in case of external table...) the database and the tables are stored in `hive/warehouse/`directory in the default container of the Hive cluster by default.

You can also use these options,

***case: hive command*** : if you want know it by command will be giving the location of where its stored.

```
describe formatted <table name>
```

***case : If you are using spark***

```
def getHiveTablePath(tableName: String, spark: SparkSession):String =
    {
       import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
      val sql: String = String.format("desc formatted %s", tableName)
      val result: DataFrame = spark.sql(sql).filter(col("col_name") === "Location")
      result.show(false) // just for debug purpose
      val info: String = result.collect().mkString(",")
      val path: String = info.split(',')(1)
      path
    }
```

Example  :

caller would be

```
    println(getHiveTablePath("src", spark)) // you can prefix schema if you have
```

Result (I executed in local so file:/ below if its hdfs hdfs:// will come):

```
+--------+------------------------------------+-------+
|col_name|data_type                           |comment|
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|Location|file:/Users/hive/spark-warehouse/src|       |
+--------+------------------------------------+-------+

file:/Users/hive/spark-warehouse/src
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify **LOCATION** , the database and the tables are stored in **hive/warehouse/ directory** in the default container of the Hive cluster by default.

reference:

[Create Hive database and tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-hive-tables#create-tables)